Pasting Google App Script from Google Sheets adds an extra set of quotes
I'm generating repetative Google app scripts through formulas in Google Sheets.
When I paste the script generated below:
function testIns2(e){
//Completed
var range1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("B4")
range1.clearContent()
var value1 = range1.getValue()
value1 = value1 + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('AdvancedButtons').getRange("C3").getValue()
range1.setValue(value1)
}

The " " doubles
//Completed
var range1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(""B4"")
range1.clearContent()
var value1 = range1.getValue()
value1 = value1 + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('AdvancedButtons').getRange(""C3"").getValue()
range1.setValue(value1)

The same thing happend just now when I pasted into Stack Overflow.
To get the quotes to work in Google Sheets in the formula generating the script I use:
="getRange("&Char(34)&A1&Char(34)&")"
This displays as: .getRange("C3").getValue()
But pasted into Google App Scripts I get a ""C3""
Any recommendations on how to prevent double quotes?
I tried using char(34) for the " and I tried using a /"/ to display the quotes as in a regex function

The best thing to do is improve your coding skills so you don't have to "cheat" using Google Sheets to write repetitive coding patterns. You might want to learn about DRY (don't repeat yourself) programming principle, and more specifically, learning from questions like Pass a JavaScript function as parameter might be helpful.
In the meantime, try the following

Join the results of your formula in a single cell,
Do a Copy - Paste as value only from the above cell to  another cell
Copy the cell content of the other cell from the formula bar.

Now, you should be able to paste the code into the Google Apps Script Editor without the double double-quotes

Thank you for information, I suspected that I would have to copy - paste, then copy - paste again. I appreciate the additional information.  As a non-programmer and small business owner, I get the DRY philosophy, but the Pass a JavaScript function is beyond my comprehension. I'm missing some fundamentals that I would have learned if I started  "at the beginning" and I'm paying for it now.
